# Excel: Selecting Specific Columns and Rows in Pivot Table and Formatting

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, pivot-table

I'm using a Pivot Table in Excel 2010, and while searching posts I find that a lot of users are frustrated like me because it doesn't keep all formats.

So what I'm trying to do is run a macro that formats columns in a Pivot table, but limited to the last row and column in the table.  I have the formatting info, but I just need to know how to apply it to specific columns and rows.

What I was thinking might work is finding the last column of the Values row, in this case "Stops per Rte" which is the last Values column; however, I have months listed at the top, so it repeats across months.  If the user filters only certain months then the # of columns will decrease.

Same goes for the # of rows: of course, the user should be able to expand/collapse rows as needed, so I only want the column format to go to the last row or just above "Grand Total", if possible.

Hopefully, this makes sense.  Thanks in advance! = )

Comment: Are you formatting using the Numberformat option of the pivot table (right-click data field) or the numberformat on the ribbon? You should be using the first option to preserve the formatting when refreshing or changing layout.

Comment: Hi there: I did fail to mention that this is strictly borders and shading.  Shading across the headers and borders around every 4 VAlues columns of each month down to the Grand Total row